# How to access only one record from my query

Tags: php, mysql

My Pastebin : http://pastebin.com/PmfDEdEw

Hi,

I am doing a bus search script and here is a table called "bus_notavailable" and it has fields as

```
nodate_id(PK)
bus_id(FK)
DD(INT 2)
MM(INT 2)
and YYYY(INT 4)
```

My Question is : Suppose Bus ID is 1 which is not available for these two dates are 15-08-2013 and 26-01-2013 so the record will filtered for this day...

The Nodates Table

```
Nodate_id             bus_id        DD     MM     YYYY
1                     1             15     08     2013
2                     1             26     01     2013
```

• so bus_notavailable.DD != '26' its showing me one record

• bus_notavailable.DD != '11' then its showing me 2 records

I know I did mistakes or don't know the solutions therefore want to find out the way to get rid of, and knew this is a issue of one to many relationship where the 'bus_notavailable' has two id of the same bus its showing me two records from 'bus' table.

So Do I need a sub-query to achieve this or is there any other methods?

Comment: Why don't you store your dates in a MySQL [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) type column?

Comment: I don't understand the logic of the question. Why choose only rownum 1? what is the condition you thought of (logically, not programmatically)?

Comment: Yes for other reason I'm doing so, although DATETIME is also good

Comment: Sorry what's the question again? :)

Comment: I want to filter my query regarding to the date (DD) of bus_notavailable.DD. That means if there is no records in bus_notavailable match to the user datepicker then it will list only buses records and will not display the record in which date the is available.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition here

```
    LEFT JOIN bus_notavailable ON bus.bus_id = bus_notavailable.bus_id
           .....
    WHERE   ...... 
            bus_notavailable.bus_id IS NULL
            AND bus_notavailable.DD != '$DD'
            AND bus_notavailable.MM != '$MM'
            AND bus_notavailable.YYYY != '$YYYY'
```

Is nonsensical because once bus_id IS NULL, there is no `bus_notavailable` record from which to compare the `DD`, `MM` or `YYYY` columns.

The condition you want is this (move the DD/MM/YYYY into the LEFT JOIN `ON` cluse):

```
    LEFT JOIN bus_notavailable ON bus.bus_id = bus_notavailable.bus_id
            AND bus_notavailable.DD = '$DD'
            AND bus_notavailable.MM = '$MM'
            AND bus_notavailable.YYYY = '$YYYY'
           .....
    WHERE   ...... 
            bus_notavailable.bus_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank You! But under your 'WHERE' clause bus_notavailable.bus_id IS NULL but here my Table do not have NULL Value it is 00

Comment: Try it and see. It's NULL because the LEFT JOIN failed. This is an existential test. The LEFT JOIN succeeds when the bus is **NOT** available on that day, which won't fit the filter `WHERE bus_notavailable.bus_id IS NULL` so it gets removed from the result

Comment: Yes it is very helpful to me and other, you said nicely the LEFT Join, without much work its solve my issues, Thank You  Richard, the Geek!

Answer (score 0):

Man)))))) First of all you didn't say what you want to achieve. If you want to select buses that are available on day DD, then you are doing right.

The reason why second row returns 2 rows because as you say you select records where DD not equal to 11. And in this table, both records are suitable. That is why you get 2 rows.

If you want to select only one buss that is available for certain date in case there are many dates in this table you should use distinct keyword.

select distinct bus where dd!=11. You will get one row))

I mean only one row for each bus. So if you have 10 buses available on that date you will have 10 records. One record for each bus.